# C# insert empty integer numbers on mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to insert on mysql table this integer variables

```
public static Int32 bat_set1_inicial { get; set; }
        public static Int32 bat_set1_final { get; set; }
        public static Int32 bat_set2_inicial { get; set; }
        public static Int32 bat_set2_final { get; set; }
        public static Int32 bat_set3_inicial { get; set; }
        public static int32 bat_set3_final { get; set; }
```

```
string tabela = "INSERT INTO BD.table(...,bat_set1_inicial,bat_set1_final,bat_set2_inicial,bat_set2_final,bat_set3_inicial,bat_set3_final,..) VALUES('"+... + "'," + bat_set1_inicial + "," + bat_set1_final + "," + bat_set2_inicial +
                        "," + bat_set2_final + "," + bat_set3_inicial + "," + bat_set3_final + ",...')";
```

when every variable have values i don't have problems, when i don't fill the variables i want that on mysql it appears empty ( on mysql is define as default value null), but appears the value 0

i try to turn null my variable but it gives error

bat_set1_inicial = null;

How could i turn nullable my variable or other solution

i don't know what to try

Comment: This question isn't about using Visual Studio, nor is it about editing your UI with the WIndows Forms Designer. And although your application might have a WinForms UI, it's certainly not relevant to your question.

Comment: You need to 1) use parameterized SQL queries so as to avoid bugs and SQL injection, and 2) probably need to use a nullable int.

Comment: Use parametrized queries instead... it should be lot easier

Comment: i make to changed to my code, i made turn my variable null able "public static Nullable<Int32> bat_set1_inicial { get; set; }" and  " bat_set1_inicial = null;"